# Is this sloka part of the Gajendra Moksha stotra in the Bhagavta Purana?

Tags: identification-request, bhagavata-purana, shloka

I came across a nice rendition of the Ganjendra Moksha stortam on YouTube but I'm not sure if it has been altered from the original.

> soham vishva-srjam vishvam
>
> avishvam vishva-vedasam
>
> vishvatmanam ajam brahma
>
> pranatosmi param padam

This and the following verses in particular (from time 6:18):

https://youtu.be/4yt_nVcZulY?t=378

Could you please confirm?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could transcribe the verses in question and [edit] them into your question. Interesting question, though, otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular prayer called **Gajendra moksha stotra** is present in 8th skandha of *Srimad bhagwatam.*

> ŚB 8.3.26

> सोऽहं विश्वसृजं विश्वमविश्वं विश्ववेदसम् ।
> विश्वात्मानमजं ब्रह्म प्रणतोऽस्मि परं पदम् ॥ २६ ॥

> so ’haṁ viśva-sṛjaṁ viśvam
> aviśvaṁ viśva-vedasam
> viśvātmānam ajaṁ brahma
> praṇato ’smi paraṁ padam

> Now, fully desiring release from material life, I offer my respectful obeisances unto that Supreme Person who is the creator of the universe, who is Himself the form of the universe and who is nonetheless transcendental to this cosmic manifestation. He is the supreme knower of everything in this world, the Supersoul of the universe. He is the unborn, supremely situated Lord. I offer my respectful obeisances unto Him.

Comment: Thank you. "Now, fully desiring release from material life" - what Sanskrit words in the shloka say this part?

Comment: @ottodidakt pardon for late reply. The sanskrit words for this particular line are not present in this shloka. But u must read the previous shloka in which the elephant is asking for moksha